# Sencha Touch conditional compilation

Tags: sencha-touch, conditional-compilation, sencha-cmd

It is slightly touched in the docs [The if directive](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/command_compiler), but not described how you can pass custom parameters to the `if` directive at the time of making a build. I want to know how can I make several different builds using Sencha Cmd just passing a certain argument/parameter to a build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the option when I can do that. 
Suppose we have some conditional parts in the code wrapped into `if` directive:

```
...
//<if myoption1>
some code here
//</if>
...
//<if myoption2>
some code here
//</if>
...
```

Then I figured out the way how I can control myoption parameters at the build state using Sencha Cmd, reading from help for sencha ant command `sencha help ant` and analyzing different build xml files used by sencha cmd during build process. And here it is:

```
sencha ant -t "Build - Testing" -p build.options=myoption1:true,myoption2:false,etc
```

Available targets can be found just typing `sencha ant` in project folder. So, prepare some shell scripts with different set of custom parameters will give you flexible builds, to a certain extent of course.

Comment: did you actually try this out? I couldn't make it work by passing options

Comment: @MoinAhmed Sure, I used this exactly as it's written above.